# ORA-00001: unique constraint primary key violated

Tags: oracle, unique-constraint

```
DELETE from dbo.T_LIAV_AGENT_STATE_APPROVAL SAP
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT UNIQUE 1 FROM MCS_SYNC_STATE_APPR APP

                inner join MCS_SYNC_NAME SN on SN.SE_NAME_ID = APP.SE_NAME_ID
                                    and SN.ACTION in('U','S')
                Where APP.SE_name_id = SAP.AV_NAME_ID
                and APP.SYNC_INSTANCE_ID = param_inst_ID);
COMMIT;

INSERT INTO dbo.T_LIAV_AGENT_STATE_APPROVAL

SELECT  UNIQUE 

    APP.SE_NAME_ID            AS AV_NAME_ID,
    APP.STATE                 AS AV_STATE,
    APP.APPROVAL_TYPE         AS AV_APPROVAL_TYPE,
    APP.START_DATE            AS AV_START_DATE,
    APP.END_DATE              AS AV_END_DATE,
    APP.APPOINTED             AS AV_APPOINTED,
    APP.RENEWAL_DATE          AS AV_RENEWAL_DATE,
    APP.LICENSE               AS AV_LICENSE,
    COMPANY_NAME_ID           as AV_COMPANY_CODE,
    SYSDATE                   AS TSTAMP,
    SYNC_USER_NAME_ID         AS AV_FIRST_USER_ID,
    SYSDATE                   AS AV_FIRST_DATE,
    NULL                      AS AV_LAST_USER_ID,
    NULL                      AS AV_LAST_DATE

FROM MCS_SYNC_STATE_APPR APP

WHERE exists (select 1 from t_liag_agent AG
                     where AG.ag_name_id = APP.SE_NAME_ID)
and APP.SYNC_INSTANCE_ID = param_inst_ID;
```

Here is the SQL part and I am getting error when I debug the code:

> ORA-00001: unique constraint primary key violated  At T_LIAV_AGENT_STATE_APPROVAL...

and these are the 2 columns which the primary key constraint relies on  `AV_NAME_ID,  AV_STATE` ..

There is no duplicate data as per me ...Do you think any other reason?

Comment: "*there is no duplicate data as per me*" - but Oracle thinks there is duplicate data and I would trust Oracle here.

Comment: One reason, you have `UNIQUE` over multiple columns including `SYSDATE`.. try `TRUNC(SYSDATE)` to nullify the time element all to `00:00:00`

Comment: @MaheswaranRavisankar All SYSDATEs in a SQL statement will resolve to exactly the same time.  See my answer to a similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7954509/sysdate-difference).

Comment: @JonHeller thanks for that great piece of info... I hope I am unaware of many things!!!!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9689412/issue-ora-00001-unique-constraint-violated-coming-in-insert-update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select statement was missing a column when compared to Insert table statement so there was this error. When i added that column to the select statement it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 5):

If you have 'CREATE TABLE' privilege, use dbms_errlog package.

1. Run script:

   ```
   begin
     dbms_errlog.create_error_log('DBO.T_LIAV_AGENT_STATE_APPROVAL');
   end;
   /
   ```
2. Run your INSERT script with an additional clause:

   ```
   INSERT INTO dbo.T_LIAV_AGENT_STATE_APPROVAL
   SELECT ...
   FROM ...
   LOG ERRORS INTO err$_T_LIAV_AGENT_STATE_APPROVAL REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED;
   ```
3. Check error logging table for errors:

   ```
   select * from err$_T_LIAV_AGENT_STATE_APPROVAL;
   ```

You will see all records, that violated constraints, and error messages.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not sure which unique constraint was violated, you can run the following SQL:

```
Select Distinct table_name
From all_indexes
Where index_name = 'CONSTRAINT_NAME';
```