# 'Insert into x select y' results in ora-01847

Tags: sql, oracle, date

So I'm trying to copy the values of a row from one table to another using the 'Insert into x select y' structure. The two tables have the exact same structure. The tables contain Timestamp(6) columns which somehow causes it to fail, I think.

Look below for the query:

```
INSERT INTO sapd SELECT sap.* FROM sap WHERE ID=:id
```

This causes the following error:

```
ORA-01847 day of month must be between 1 and last day of month 
Cause: The day of the month listed in a date is invalid for the 
specified month. The day of the month (DD) must be between 1 
and the number of days in that month.
```

The fixes I find for this error are to cast the values to a date with TO_DATE(), but seeing as I am doing a 'select *' I can't exactly do this.
I've tried to run this query from code (.NET) and from the Oracle SQL Developer tool, both with the same results.

Does anybody have any idea how to fix this?

---

The table definition (only one cause the other one is identical). (And yes, I know the table is kind of large, but it's a legacy project.)

```
CREATE TABLE sapd
   (    "ID_STAGEPLAATS" NUMBER, 
    "STUDIEJAAR" NVARCHAR2(9), 
    "STAGE_AFSTUDEREN" NVARCHAR2(35), 
    "POS_ADVIES" CHAR(1 BYTE), 
    "BEVESTIGD" CHAR(1 BYTE), 
    "BEGIN" TIMESTAMP (6), 
    "EIND" TIMESTAMP (6), 
    "AANTAL_DAGEN" NUMBER, 
    "ID_BEDRIJF" NUMBER, 
    "AFDELING" NVARCHAR2(100), 
    "VERDIEPING" NVARCHAR2(50), 
    "KAMERNR" NVARCHAR2(25), 
    "OPDRACHT_D" CLOB, 
    "ID_CONTPERS" NUMBER, 
    "TITEL" NVARCHAR2(15), 
    "BEGEL_VL" NVARCHAR2(25), 
    "BEGEL_VV" NVARCHAR2(10), 
    "BEGEL_ROEPNAAM" NVARCHAR2(25), 
    "BEGEL_NAAM" NVARCHAR2(50), 
    "BEGEL_MV" NVARCHAR2(1), 
    "TEL_BEGELEIDER" NVARCHAR2(50), 
    "FAX_BEGELEIDER" NVARCHAR2(50), 
    "E_MAIL_BEGELEIDER" NVARCHAR2(200), 
    "MOBIEL_BEGELEIDER" NVARCHAR2(50), 
    "STUDENTENNUMMER" NUMBER, 
    "TEL_STUDENT" NVARCHAR2(50), 
    "FAX_STUDENT" NVARCHAR2(50), 
    "E_MAIL_STUDENT" NVARCHAR2(50), 
    "WOONADRES_STUDENT" NVARCHAR2(50), 
    "PC_STUDENT" NVARCHAR2(10), 
    "PLAATS_STUDENT" NVARCHAR2(50), 
    "TEL_STUDENT_TIJDELIJKE_THUIS" NVARCHAR2(15), 
    "DOCENT1" NVARCHAR2(50), 
    "DOCENT2" NVARCHAR2(50), 
    "THUISBERICHT" TIMESTAMP (6), 
    "PRES_DATUM" TIMESTAMP (6), 
    "PRES_TIJD" TIMESTAMP (6), 
    "PRES_PLAATS" NVARCHAR2(50), 
    "PRES_ONDERWERP" NVARCHAR2(255), 
    "BRDNG_BEDR" NUMBER, 
    "BRDNG_VRSLG" NUMBER, 
    "BRDNG_PRES" NUMBER, 
    "BRDNG_TOT" NUMBER, 
    "VERGOEDING" NUMBER, 
    "AFSPRAKEN_D" CLOB, 
    "OPMERKING_STUDENT_D" CLOB, 
    "OPMERKING_BEDRIJF_D" CLOB, 
    "STAGE_ADVIES" NVARCHAR2(5), 
    "VERWERVINGSBEDRIJF1_ID" NUMBER, 
    "VERWERVINGSBEDRIJF2_ID" NUMBER, 
    "AFSPRAKEN_BEDRIJF1_D" CLOB, 
    "AFSPRAKEN_BEDRIJF2_D" CLOB, 
    "BEVESTIGD_DATUM" TIMESTAMP (6), 
    "OPENSTAANDESTAGE_BEDRIJF" NUMBER, 
    "OS_VERWERVINGSBEDRIJF1" NUMBER, 
    "OS_VERWERVINGSBEDRIJF2" NUMBER, 
    "VALUTA" NVARCHAR2(10), 
    "STATUS_BEVESTIGING" NVARCHAR2(20), 
    "AANTAL_UREN" NUMBER, 
    "OPMERKING_D" CLOB, 
    "VOORKEURSDOCENT" NVARCHAR2(50), 
    "MOBIEL_STUDENT" NVARCHAR2(50), 
    "EXTRA1" NVARCHAR2(200), 
    "EXTRA2" NVARCHAR2(200), 
    "EXTRA3" NVARCHAR2(200), 
    "ORIGINELE__ID" NUMBER, 
    "AFGEMELD_VOLGPLUS" CHAR(1 BYTE), 
    "AANGEMAAKTDOOR" NVARCHAR2(100), 
    "AANGEMAAKTOP" TIMESTAMP (6), 
    "LAATSTGEWIJZIGDDOOR" NVARCHAR2(100), 
    "LAATSTGEWIJZIGDOP" TIMESTAMP (6), 
    "INSTITUUT" NVARCHAR2(50), 
    "ID_SIS" NUMBER, 
    "ID_SIS2" NUMBER(38,0), 
    "ID_VELDWERKER" NUMBER(38,0), 
    "ID_BEDRIJF_ORIGINEEL" NUMBER, 
    "ID_CONTACT_ORIGINEEL" NUMBER, 
    "STUDNR_ORI" NVARCHAR2(250), 
    "AANTAL_UREN_ORI" NUMBER(38,1), 
    "AANTAL_DAGEN_ORI" NUMBER(38,1), 
    "STAGE_VERPLAATST" CHAR(1 BYTE), 
    "REISSCHEMA_D" CLOB, 
    "AFSPRAKEN" NCLOB, 
    "AFSPRAKEN_BEDRIJF1" NCLOB, 
    "AFSPRAKEN_BEDRIJF2" NCLOB, 
    "OPDRACHT" NCLOB, 
    "OPMERKING" NCLOB, 
    "OPMERKING_BEDRIJF" NCLOB, 
    "OPMERKING_STUDENT" NCLOB, 
    "REISSCHEMA" NCLOB, 
    "EXTRA4" NVARCHAR2(200), 
    "EXTRA5" NVARCHAR2(200), 
    "OPMERKING_VAN_BEDRIJF" NCLOB, 
    "LAND_STUDENT" NVARCHAR2(50), 
    "EXTRA_INFO" NVARCHAR2(50), 
    "ST_VIEWAGREEMENT" CHAR(1 BYTE) DEFAULT 0, 
    "BESCHIKBAAR_MA" CHAR(1 BYTE) DEFAULT 0, 
    "BESCHIKBAAR_DI" CHAR(1 BYTE) DEFAULT 0, 
    "BESCHIKBAAR_WO" CHAR(1 BYTE) DEFAULT 0, 
    "BESCHIKBAAR_DO" CHAR(1 BYTE) DEFAULT 0, 
    "BESCHIKBAAR_VR" CHAR(1 BYTE) DEFAULT 0, 
    "STUDENT_CHANGED_INFO" CHAR(1 BYTE) DEFAULT 0, 
    "STUDENT_CHANGED_INFO_DATE" TIMESTAMP (6), 
    "BEG_2_TITEL" NVARCHAR2(15), 
    "BEG_2_VL" NVARCHAR2(25), 
    "BEG_2_VV" NVARCHAR2(10), 
    "BEG_2_ROEPNAAM" NVARCHAR2(25), 
    "BEG_2_NAAM" NVARCHAR2(50), 
    "BEG_2_MV" NVARCHAR2(1), 
    "BEG_2_TEL" NVARCHAR2(50), 
    "BEG_2_FAX" NVARCHAR2(50), 
    "BEG_2_E_MAIL" NVARCHAR2(200), 
    "BEG_2_MOBIEL" NVARCHAR2(50), 
    "BEG_BESCHIKBAAR_MA" CHAR(1 BYTE), 
    "BEG_BESCHIKBAAR_DI" CHAR(1 BYTE), 
    "BEG_BESCHIKBAAR_WO" CHAR(1 BYTE), 
    "BEG_BESCHIKBAAR_DO" CHAR(1 BYTE), 
    "BEG_BESCHIKBAAR_VR" CHAR(1 BYTE), 
    "BEG_2_BESCHIKBAAR_MA" CHAR(1 BYTE), 
    "BEG_2_BESCHIKBAAR_DI" CHAR(1 BYTE), 
    "BEG_2_BESCHIKBAAR_WO" CHAR(1 BYTE), 
    "BEG_2_BESCHIKBAAR_DO" CHAR(1 BYTE), 
    "BEG_2_BESCHIKBAAR_VR" CHAR(1 BYTE), 
    "MERGE_INSTITUUT" NVARCHAR2(100), 
    "MOTIVATION_STUDENT" NCLOB, 
    "ROB_FROM" NVARCHAR2(10), 
    "ROB_TO" NVARCHAR2(10), 
    "ROB_ID" NVARCHAR2(10), 
    "STUDENTNR_ITSIS" NUMBER, 
    "INSTITUUT_SLHAPO" NVARCHAR2(50), 
    "STUDENTNR_VOOR_ITSIS" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
    "BESCHIKBAAR_ZA" CHAR(1 BYTE) DEFAULT 0, 
    "BESCHIKBAAR_ZO" CHAR(1 BYTE) DEFAULT 0, 
    "BEG_BESCHIKBAAR_ZA" CHAR(1 BYTE), 
    "BEG_BESCHIKBAAR_ZO" CHAR(1 BYTE), 
    "BEG_2_BESCHIKBAAR_ZA" CHAR(1 BYTE), 
    "BEG_2_BESCHIKBAAR_ZO" CHAR(1 BYTE), 
    "EXTRA6" NVARCHAR2(200), 
    "EXTRA7" NVARCHAR2(200), 
    "EXTRA8" NVARCHAR2(200), 
    "EXTRA9" NVARCHAR2(200), 
    "EXTRA10" NVARCHAR2(200), 
    "EXTRA11" NVARCHAR2(200), 
    "EXTRA12" NVARCHAR2(200), 
    "EXTRA13" NVARCHAR2(200), 
    "EXTRA14" NVARCHAR2(200), 
    "EXTRA15" NVARCHAR2(200), 
    "EXTRA_CHAR1" CHAR(1 BYTE) DEFAULT 0, 
    "EXTRA_CHAR2" CHAR(1 BYTE) DEFAULT 0, 
    "EXTRA_CHAR3" CHAR(1 BYTE) DEFAULT 0, 
    "EXTRA_CHAR4" CHAR(1 BYTE) DEFAULT 0, 
    "EXTRA_CHAR5" CHAR(1 BYTE) DEFAULT 0, 
    "EXTRA_CHAR6" CHAR(1 BYTE) DEFAULT 0, 
    "EXTRA_CHAR7" CHAR(1 BYTE) DEFAULT 0, 
    "EXTRA_CHAR8" CHAR(1 BYTE) DEFAULT 0, 
    "EXTRA_CHAR9" CHAR(1 BYTE) DEFAULT 0, 
    "EXTRA_CHAR10" CHAR(1 BYTE) DEFAULT 0, 
    "EXTRA_DATE1" TIMESTAMP (6), 
    "EXTRA_DATE2" TIMESTAMP (6), 
    "EXTRA_DATE3" TIMESTAMP (6), 
    "EXTRA_DATE4" TIMESTAMP (6), 
    "EXTRA_DATE5" TIMESTAMP (6), 
    "EXTRA_DATE6" TIMESTAMP (6), 
    "EXTRA_DATE7" TIMESTAMP (6), 
    "EXTRA_DATE8" TIMESTAMP (6), 
    "EXTRA_DATE9" TIMESTAMP (6), 
    "EXTRA_DATE10" TIMESTAMP (6), 
    "ONDERNEMINGSZIN" NCLOB, 
    "EXTRA_DATE11" TIMESTAMP (6), 
    "EXTRA_DATE12" TIMESTAMP (6), 
    "EXTRA_DATE13" TIMESTAMP (6), 
    "REVIEW_INGEVULD" CHAR(1 BYTE), 
    "REVIEW_REMINDER" CHAR(1 BYTE), 
    "REVIEW_GUID" NVARCHAR2(100), 
    "CUSTOM_INTERNSHIP_DAYS" NVARCHAR2(255), 
    "LWO_REMINDER_SENT" TIMESTAMP (6), 
    "REASON" NCLOB, 
    "REJECTOR_ID" NUMBER, 
    "REJECTOR_TYPE" NUMBER, 
    "OPLEIDING" NVARCHAR2(100)
   )
```

Comment: Show us the table definitions.

Comment: You should avoid `select *` except when prototyping and inside an `EXISTS` operator. I would guess that there's a column order mismatch so see if it is resolved by using *explicit* column lists in both the `INSERT` and `SELECT` rather than omitting the columns from the `INSERT` and using `SELECT *`.

Comment: See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26745822/2141278), it shows how to define the reason of the error.

Comment: Please show also the definition of the other table. Most likely it is not the same.

Comment: Compare the two tables with this statement: `SELECT COLUMN_ID, a.column_name, b.column_name, a.data_type, b.data_type 
FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS a
 FULL OUTER JOIN USER_TAB_COLUMNS b USING (COLUMN_ID)
WHERE a.table_name = 'SAPD'
 AND b.table_name = 'SAP'
 AND ( a.column_name <> b.column_name OR a.data_type <> b.data_type );`

Comment: Why so many `NVARCHAR2` columns? Nowadays they are typically not needed anymore due to UTF-8.

Comment: Like I said, it's a legacy project that started more than 15 years ago and managers see no need for refactoring/improving

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Damien suggested, there is indeed an order mismatch within the table definitions. This results into errors

Let's say the two tables definitions 1 and 2 have the columns a, b, c and d; but for Table 1 it's in the order a, b, c, d and Table 2 has it in the order a, c, b, d. If I now try to do

```
INSERT INTO Table_1 SELECT * FROM Table_2
```

Then the value of c in Table_2 would be put into the value of b in Table_1. This will cause problems.

For my own problem it will try to put a non-date value into a date column.

Answer (score 1):

One solution to avoid `SELECT *` is to generate dynamic SQL statement like this:

```
DECLARE
    sqlstr VARCHAR2(30000);
BEGIN
    sqlstr := 'INSERT INTO sapd ('
    FOR aCol IN (SELECT column_name FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'SAPD' ORDER BY COLUMN_ID) LOOP
        sqlstr := sqlstr || aCol.column_name||',';
    END LOOP;
    sqlstr := REGEXP_REPLACE(sqlstr, ',$', ')');

    sqlstr := sqlstr || ' SELECT ';
    FOR aCol IN (SELECT column_name FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'SAPD' ORDER BY COLUMN_ID) LOOP
        sqlstr := sqlstr || aCol.column_name||',';
    END LOOP;
    sqlstr := REGEXP_REPLACE(sqlstr, ',$');

    sqlstr := sqlstr || ' FROM sap WHERE ID = :id';

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sqlstr using id;
end;
```